# std::unique_ptr from virtual classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, unique-ptr

How to use std::unique_ptr with polymorphism idiom?
For example:

```c++
class Abstract {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class Child1 final : public Abstract {
    void foo() override;
}

class Child2 final : public Abstract {
    void foo() override;
}

void bar(const Abstract& a) {
    std::unique_ptr<Abstract> ptr = std::make_unique<Abstract>(a); // exception :(
}

int main() {
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;

    bar(c1);
    bar(c2);
}
```

How to initialize unique_ptr from any child of Abstract ?

Comment: You cannot initialize it from "any" child, you have to choose a specific one in the initialization: `unique_ptr<Abstract> ptr = make_unique<Child1>`. After all, you can only have an instance of either `Child1` or `Child2`, but not `Abstract`. You have to choose a child at some point.

Comment: @Den-Jason your code has UB (segfault)

Comment: @a_nR1085__i your question is not clear about what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Are you, perhaps, looking for the `clone()` idiom?

Comment: Try this - https://godbolt.org/z/3d6o6a1Pr

I _really_ don't recommend that approach, though.  When the unique_ptr goes out of scope, you'll find that the object becomes destroyed.

Comment: Don't forget to add a virtual destructor to the base class.

Comment: This issue is only tangentially related to `std::unique_ptr`.  If you tried to say `Abstract* ptr = new Abstract(a);` you would have the same problem: you cannot instantiate an `Abstract` because it has a pure-virtual method.  Either allocate the object in `main` and pass a (possibly smart) pointer to it to `bar` or use the clone pattern from @Eljays's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **clone** idiom, which allows a polymorphic clone (or *copy*).

```
#include <memory>

namespace {

class Abstract {
public:
    virtual ~Abstract() = default;
    Abstract() = default;
    Abstract(Abstract const&) = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Abstract> clone() const = 0;
};

class Child1 final : public Abstract {
public:
    void foo() override;
    std::unique_ptr<Abstract> clone() const override {
        return std::make_unique<Child1>(*this);
    }
};

class Child2 final : public Abstract {
public:
    void foo() override;
    std::unique_ptr<Abstract> clone() const override {
        return std::make_unique<Child2>(*this);
    }
};

void bar(const Abstract& a) {
    std::unique_ptr<Abstract> ptr = a.clone();
}

} // anon

int main() {
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;

    bar(c1);
    bar(c2);
}

void Child1::foo() { }
void Child2::foo() { }
```

Answer (score 2):

When instantiating an object, the program needs to know the concrete class, otherwise it cannot allocate proper amount of memory for that. `std::make_unqie` makes a whole new object, not just a pointer, and you cannot make an object of an abstract class (`Abstract`) here:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Abstract> ptr = std::make_unique<Abstract>(a);
```

The thing you are missing is that you can assign pointers of base class to pointers of derived classes:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Abstract> ptr = std::make_unique<Child2>();
```

Comment: Just note that, while this solution will compile, it won't cleanup the `Child2` object correctly when the `unique_ptr<Abstract>` is destroyed, because `Abstract` is missing a `virtual` destructor.